# JSON data source - Sub-Array

Tags: arrays, json, jasper-reports, datasource

I'm using *iReport* for designing a *JasperReports* templates. I have to use a *json* datasource. Let's make an example. Suppose my *json* datasource is:

```
{
    "field1" : "value1",
    "list" : [
        {
            "field3" : "value3"
        },
        {
            "field3" : "value4";
        }
    ]
}
```

Then I create the *json* datasource just pointing to the file with data; after this I create a query string as:

```xml
<queryString language="json">
    <![CDATA[list]]>
</queryString>
<field name="field3" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[field3]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
```

In this way I am able to print a list of values (so my report is printing value3 and then value4) by just having:

```xml
<textField>
    <reportElement x="74" y="20" width="100" height="20" uuid="b88d96bc-87bd-4dfd-a246-1898dfec1f4a"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{field3}]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Unfortunately I am not able to replicate the same behaviour in case I want to display also "field1" (so I can't use the queryString "list", because I want to use also the data outside the list).

Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this for specified index

```
<queryString language="json">
    <![CDATA[]]>
</queryString>
<field name="field3" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[list[0].field3]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
```